# Why doesn't this top loop work?

Tags: c++, file-io

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to get a bunch of non-repeating vectors. Could someone please help me by telling me where my typo is? I'm just blind right now. It runs just fine, no errors. But it doesn't give any output. I would really appreciate this. I'm just building a library for myself.

```
class vectGet {

    public:
    long long integral = 0;
    long long t = 14;

    string fname = "";

    long s_nop(long t);
} n;

long vectGet::s_nop(long t) {
    n.integral++;
    if (abs(round((n.t*1.618)*n.t-(n.integral+0.618))-1) <= 4294967296)
        return (abs(round((n.t*1.618)*n.t-(n.integral+0.618))-1));
    else
        return (abs(round(sqrt(n.t))+(round(sqrt(n.t))*round(sqrt(n.integral))+1)));
}

int main() {


    long bn=0;
    printf("How many Vectors should we make? ");
    cin >> bn;

    vector<long> deriv;


    if (bn <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid number of vectors, Exiting");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nOutput File: ");
    cin >> n.fname;

    if (n.fname=="") {
        printf("You must choose a filename to continue...");
        return 1;
    }

    ofstream out;
    out.open(n.fname.c_str(), std::ios::out);

    for (long i=1;i<=bn;i++) {
        n.t=n.s_nop(n.t);
        for (long j=0;j<deriv.size();j++) {
            if (n.t == deriv[j]) {
                i--;
                break;
            }
            deriv.push_back(n.t);
            printf(".");
        }
    }

    cout << "Writing to file.." << endl;
    for (long j=0;j<deriv.size();j++)
        out << deriv[j] << " ";

    out.close();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Can you post a mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? What do you mean by 'no output', it isn't making a file? Are you closing the out stream?

Comment: I tried to be with the mcve rule. that's not all the code. I do get a file touched. I do close the outstream. But it won't even enter that top loop. `bn` will hold the value, but the counter `i` doesn't want to do anything and it skips the loop.

Comment: So in advancing your question, there is no file output except that the file has been created.

Comment: Can you edit to fix the formatting? It's pretty hard to read. That looks like a few sections of code pasted together to look like one. I'd step through your code with a debugger -- look for things like, what is the value of bn (where is bn assigned? If it is <1, you won't loop).

Comment: Okay, @AndyM I put the rest of the code up.

Comment: It'd be good to avoid magic numbers like `4294967296`.  If you mean `ULONG_MAX + 1.0` then write that. Or `UINT32_MAX + 1.0`, etc.  Note that it causes *undefined behaviour* to convert an out-of-range float to integer type, so perhaps you really want `LONG_MAX + 1.0` here.

Comment: also , temporary variables are a good idea compared to repeating complicated expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j<deriv.size()` is 0, so it never runs the inner loop and then it doesn't write anything into the file.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. My code is completely usable now!

Comment: no problem - If this fixed it, mark as solved please =) Look into debugging (I dunno what tools you used, but gdb is really really useful and pretty easy, unless you have a visual debugger of some sort like in visual studio)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the missing code. This will create a list of any number of vectors under a limit to be created. All of them can be reproduced in order, with a state of randomness to them.

```
    ofstream out;
    out.open(n.fname.c_str(), std::ios::out);

    for (long i=1;i<=bn;i++) {
        n.t=n.s_nop(n.t);
        deriv.push_back(n.t);
        for (long j=1;j<deriv.size()-1;j++) {
            if (n.t == deriv[j-1]) {
                i--;
                deriv.pop_back();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Writing to file.." << endl;
    for (long j=0;j<deriv.size();j++)
        out << deriv[j] << " ";

    out.close();
    return 0;   
}
```